# FunctionApp in Java: debug via Visual Studio Code - ConnectException

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, azure-functions, vscode-debugger

I try to debug a FunctionApp written in Java using Visual Studio Code and I get the following error message:

[image: image desription here]

I am using default host.json settings:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Attach to Java Functions",
            "type": "java",
            "request": "attach",
            "hostName": "127.0.0.1",
            "port": 5005,
            "preLaunchTask": "func: host start"
        }
    ]
}
```

Do you have any idea how to resolve the issue?

Comment: Have you looked at [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/43180) page?

Answer (score 0):

**From our end, we tried to debug the Azure Functions Java with the same configuration in `launch.json`, worked successfully**:

[image]

**`tasks.json`**

```
{
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
{
"type": "func",
"command": "host start",
"problemMatcher": "$func-java-watch",
"isBackground": true,
"options": {
"cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/target/azure-functions/AzJavaFuncHttpTrig-1649844396189"
},
"dependsOn": "package (functions)"
},
{
"label": "package (functions)",
"command": "mvn clean package",
"type": "shell",
"group": {
"kind": "build",
"isDefault": true
}
}
]
}
```

**Result**:

[image: JavaAFVsCodeDebugging]

**As [Steven-MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13037676/steven-msft) suggested this similar [issue-solution](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/43180) and most of the workarounds say, adding the `JAVA_OPTS` parameter to the `local.settings.json` helps you to debug the Azure Functions successfully**.

Note: If the issue still persists, please re-open the issue on the [GitHub-VSCode-AzureFunctionsJava-Debugger-Issues43180](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/43180).